# AHK: How to use a Hotkey in conjunction with GUI

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, gui

My GUI works fine.

Here is a screenshot of my Edit box, GUI:

[image]

<kbd>F1</kbd> fires the script.
I would then input 1, 2, 3, or 4, and Click <kbd>Submit</kbd> or hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>; <strike>which Enter doesn't currently get accepted but sends it into a hidden mode or something unbeknownst to me that's happening in AHK world.</strike> -- fixed by davidmneedham -- thanks!

**code**: not working as fully desired

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

F1::

    aa := "1) opt 1 or (f)"
    bb := "2) opt 2 (v)"
    cc := "3) open opt 3"
    dd := "4) open opt 4"

    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y50  w100 h30, %aa%
    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y70  w100 h30, %bb%
    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y90  w300 h30, %cc%
    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y110 w300 h30, %dd%

    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y140 w50  h20, Selection:
    Gui, Add,   Edit, x100 y140 w100 h20 vChoice
    Gui, Add,   Text, x205 y140 w300 h30, (press ENTER)


    ;Gui, Add, Button, x50  y170 w50 h30  default gCancel, Cancel 
    ;Gui, Add, Button, x130 y170 w50 h30  gSubmit, Submit

    ;Enter command fix by davidmneedham on StackExchangs thanks!        
    Gui, Add, Button, x50  y170 w50 h30  gCancel, Cancel 
    Gui, Add, Button, x130 y170 w50 h30  default gSubmit, Submit

    Gui, Color, EEAA99
    Gui +LastFound  ; Make the GUI window the last found window for use by the line below.
    WinSet, TransColor, ff00ff
    Gui, Show, w350 h250, Enter Selection

;I even tried a while loop, here but it caused other problems
;while(true) 
;{ 
;  If (GetKeyState("f"))
;  { 
;     msgbox, f pressed
;     break 
;  } 
;}

return


Submit: 
    Gui, Submit

    if (Choice = "2")
    {
        msgbox chose 2
    }
    else if (Choice = "3")
    {
        msgbox chose 3
    }
    else if (Choice = "4")
    {
        msgbox chose 4
    }
    else
    {   
        msgbox chose 1
    }

    ButtonCancel:
        Gui, destroy
    return

;One suggestion I tried this

#If WinActive("Download ahk_exe AutoHotkey.exe")
    f:: Send 2{Tab 2}{Enter}
    v:: Send 3{Tab 2}{Enter}
#If
```

What I am trying to incorporate is this:
<kbd>F1</kbd>, ENTER 1,2,3,4
OR plainly
press <kbd>f</kbd> to fire "2, ENTER"
press <kbd>v</kbd> to fire "3, ENTER"

I've looked at the this code from [(LINK CODE HERE_HOTKEYS)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and looking at this [(LINK CODE HERE_KEYPRESS)](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/94724-capture-single-key-press/):

Investigating code:

```
#SingleInstance force

Input, Key, L1

MsgBox You pressed %Key%!

OnExit ExitSub
return

ExitSub:
ExitApp
```

I can't seem how to incorporate this into 
<kbd>F1</kbd> firing the script and accepting the 
GUI original code OR accept <kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd>, in 
which any of the line will end the script 
and will not run again until <kbd>F1</kbd> if pressed.

```
Recap:

F1 fires script 
2, Enter 
or 
3, Enter 
or 
4, Enter 
or 
f 
or 
v 
... ends the script until F1 pressed once more.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your window closes without any action when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is that the Cancel button is listed as your default action.

Change these lines:

```
Gui, Add, Button, x50  y170 w50 h30  default gCancel, Cancel 
Gui, Add, Button, x130 y170 w50 h30  gSubmit, Submit
```

And make the Submit button the default action:

```
Gui, Add, Button, x50  y170 w50 h30  gCancel, Cancel 
Gui, Add, Button, x130 y170 w50 h30  default gSubmit, Submit
```

The reason your context-sensitive hotkeys do not work is because you have the wrong WinTitle: your window title is "Enter Selection". Use the following lines instead

```
#If WinActive("Enter Selection")
  f:: Send 1{Tab 2}{Enter}
  v:: Send 2{Tab 2}{Enter}
#If
```

**The complete functional script is below:**

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force

F1::

    aa := "1) opt 1 or (f)"
    bb := "2) opt 2 (v)"
    cc := "3) open opt 3"
    dd := "4) open opt 4"

    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y50  w100 h30, %aa%
    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y70  w100 h30, %bb%
    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y90  w300 h30, %cc%
    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y110 w300 h30, %dd%

    Gui, Add,   Text, x50  y140 w50  h20, Selection:
    Gui, Add,   Edit, x100 y140 w100 h20 vChoice
    Gui, Add,   Text, x205 y140 w300 h30, (press ENTER)

    Gui, Add, Button, x50  y170 w50 h30  gCancel, Cancel
    Gui, Add, Button, x130 y170 w50 h30  default gSubmit, Submit

    Gui, Color, EEAA99
    WinSet, TransColor, ff00ff
    Gui, Show, w350 h250, Enter Selection

return

#If WinActive("Enter Selection")
    f:: Send 1{Tab 2}{Enter}
    v:: Send 2{Tab 2}{Enter}
#If

Submit: 
    Gui, Submit

    if (Choice = "2")
    {
        msgbox chose 2
    }
    else if (Choice = "3")
    {
        msgbox chose 3
    }
    else if (Choice = "4")
    {
        msgbox chose 4
    }
    else
    {   
        msgbox chose 1
    }

    Gui, Destroy
return

Cancel:
    Gui, Destroy
return
```

Comment: Aha, good to know. AHK for programmers... but whom also cut/paste code LOL. But the main concern is [f ]and [v] to fire, but to fire without being a new hotkey after f1's functionality + GUI destroy. So, up one for good share. Not an answer per say, but a good comment.

Comment: Partially answered, thanks. Credit, where credit is due in my mod' question with your updated info.

Comment: I updated my answer to address the second portion of your question.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the logic and syntax because I don't fully understand. I got this suggestion from a user. I thought it was if AHK was active and that "was" the actual syntax. So it's a syntax that fol.ows....? "Selection" or "Enter Selection"? Where exactly or what line of my given code? Would you mind to do a cut/paste mine + yours? Thx!

Comment: Ah, "Enter Selection" is the title of my window?! LOL

Comment: Yes, sir. Please do a cut/paste of my code with your edits. Applause! Bow bow.

Comment: My request if fully for future spectators for easy inspection. Great job! And much thanks!